# How to convert symbols "&'<> to entities &quot; &amp; &apos; &lt; &gt; in Perl

Tags: perl

What is the simplest method in Perl to convert special symbols `"&'<>` to entities `&quot; &amp; &apos; &lt; &gt;` in Perl? It is easy to write functions like this, but I think this problem has been solved a lot of times and there is no need to write your own functions.

```
sub add_entities {
    my ($text) = @_;

    $text =~ s/&/&amp;/g;
    $text =~ s/"/&quot;/g;
    $text =~ s/'/&apos;/g;
    $text =~ s/</&lt;/g;
    $text =~ s/>/&gt;/g;

    return $text;
}

sub remove_entities {
    my ($text) = @_;

    $text =~ s/&quot;/"/g;
    $text =~ s/&amp;/&/g;
    $text =~ s/&apos;/'/g;
    $text =~ s/&lt;/</g;
    $text =~ s/&gt;/>/g;

    return $text;
}
```

Comment: [HTML::Entities](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/HTML-Parser-3.71/lib/HTML/Entities.pm)

Comment: @raina77ow, HTML doesn't have `&apos;`, so it seems the OP is dealing with XML. HTML::Entities is not appropriate for XML (except perhaps XHTML). (Not that the OP's verison aren't much better. They are horribly broken too.)

Comment: I agree that using XML writing library (and its own escaping tools) is way better when you deal with XML. I disagree that 'use XML::LibXML' is a proper answer to the question _as given_. )

Comment: @raina77ow, Who are you disagreeing with? Noone said that.

Comment: Be careful with the order of the replacement in the two routines. Consider `$s="abc&lt;def"; $t=remove_entities(add_entities($s)); printf "%s  %s  %s\n", $s, $s eq $t ? "==" : "<>" , $t;`. The `remove_entities` routine should reverse the order of changes made in `add_entities`.

Answer (score 0):

You should never ever need `remove_entities`. Your parser shouldn't return any entities. Seems you have a horribly broken parser. I recommend XML::LibXML.

Same goes for `add_entities` XML. The XML writing library will handle all of that for you. You could use XML::LibXML for this too, but XML::Writer is much simpler to use for this task.

Note that both of your routines are horribly broken. `add_entities` doesn't consider character set. `remove_entities` doesn't handle numerical and entities outside of the base XML spec.